# Integral with solution tanh

Tags: integration

I have the equation: $0,5 (y')^2 = 0,25 y^4 - 0,5y^2$ and have to get via integration by parts to the solution: $y(x)=\tanh \frac {x-x_0} {\sqrt 2}$.

I already tried to get to $\frac 1 {1-x²}$ in the integral via completing the square but I always have a square root over the expression in the denominator.

Comment: It is a "separable" ODE. Do you known the classical method to solve this kind of equation ?